# How To Create a Custom Action for the Center Tab Bar Item Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift4

i would like to create a custom action for the center tab bar item. My code is

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let homeTabBarItem = generateNavController(vc: HomeViewController(), title: "Home", image:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "address_book"))
        let workOrderTabBarItem = generateNavController(vc: SecondViewController(), title: "Work Order", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "address_book") )
        let actionItemTabBarItem = generateNavController(vc: ActionViewController(), title:"", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "address_book") )
        let requestTabBarItem = generateNavController(vc: ThirdViewController(), title: "Request", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "address_book") )
        let settingsTabBarItem =  generateNavController(vc: FourthViewController(), title: "Settings", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "address_book"))

        UINavigationBar.appearance().prefersLargeTitles = true

        viewControllers = [homeTabBarItem, workOrderTabBarItem, actionItemTabBarItem, requestTabBarItem, settingsTabBarItem]
        }
    
    fileprivate func generateNavController(vc: UIViewController, title: String, image: UIImage) -> UINavigationController {
        vc.navigationItem.title = title
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        navController.title = title
        navController.tabBarItem.image = image
        return navController
    }
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController.isKind(of: ActionViewController.self) {
            let vc =  ActionViewController()
            vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
            self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Initially my tabBar should looked regular tabBar but when the middle item is pressed should pop up screen like this(view image bellow)
[PopUp Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7PfG.jpg)

Am i remotely close to creating this task, and if anyone can help me i would appreciate it.
*Sorry if the post is not correctly formatted, it's my first time posting on stackoverflow.

Comment: Basically the whole idea is impossible. This ActionViewController cannot live two different lives simultaneously. It cannot be a normal tab bar item and also summon a presented view controller.

Comment: Should i make it as a UIButton, and then assign an action to the button ?

Comment: Yes, that’s more what I was thinking.